# Using .getas to save a chart blob as an image gives Service Error in Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-visualization

After creating a chart in google sheets I attempt to save that chart as and image. I am using .getAs('image/png'). I get service error: spreadsheet on this line. I have tried a variety of syntax from similar issues online and none are working.

```
function CheckboxLogic() {

 var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); //Main worksheet 
 ws.insertSheet('QuoteID'); //Create a new sheet using QuoteID for the name
 var ts = ws.getSheetByName('QuoteID'); //Target sheet


  //Create a chart from data copied to target sheet
  var chart = ts.newChart()
  .asTableChart()
  .addRange(ts.getRange('C1:F5'))
  .setMergeStrategy(Charts.ChartMergeStrategy.MERGE_COLUMNS)
  .setTransposeRowsAndColumns(false)
  .setNumHeaders(-1)
  .setHiddenDimensionStrategy(Charts.ChartHiddenDimensionStrategy.IGNORE_BOTH)
  .setOption('bubble.stroke', '#000000')
  .setPosition(9, 5, 13, 8)
  .build();
  ts.insertChart(chart);

  //save chart as image
  var mychart = ts.getCharts()[0].getAs('image/png');
 //This throws the Service Error  
}
```

Here is the execution transcript

```
[19-08-07 13:42:14:205 EDT] Sheet.insertChart([EmbeddedChart]) [0.345 seconds]
[19-08-07 13:42:14:353 EDT] Sheet.getCharts() [0.147 seconds]
[19-08-07 13:42:14:416 EDT] EmbeddedChart.getAs([image/png]) [0.063 seconds]
[19-08-07 13:42:14:427 EDT] Execution failed: Service error: Spreadsheets (line 22, file "Code") [0.974 seconds total runtime]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Check out [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -- with GAS errors, it would be most helpful to include the execution transcript, and with all questions, it would be useful to remove irrelevant code and provide a minimal example.

Comment: Reduced code. Not sure what you mean by execution transcript. When my script runs I get the following error: Service error: Spreadsheets. When I click details it says the same error. Could you explain execution transcript. Thanks!

Comment: From the Script Editor, click View -> [Execution Transcript](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting#execution_transcript)

Comment: Found it. Here is the last few lines. Doesn't shed much light.```[19-08-07 00:58:04:994 EDT] Sheet.insertChart([EmbeddedChart]) [0.297 seconds]
[19-08-07 00:58:05:154 EDT] Sheet.getCharts() [0.159 seconds]
[19-08-07 00:58:05:265 EDT] EmbeddedChart.getAs([image/png]) [0.111 seconds]
[19-08-07 00:58:05:351 EDT] Execution failed: Service error: Spreadsheets (line 110, file "Code") [3.186 seconds total runtime]```

Answer (score 1):

### It seems like there is currently a bug for the `getAs()` method for table charts.

I suggest you to file it on https://issuetracker.google.com/.

In the mean time, consider using other chart types where `getAs()` works as intended.

Comment: Thank you! I will try and post this bug on issuetracker.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue and entered a bug over a year ago.  It was working for months and suddenly stopped working for table charts only.

I was adding these charts to emails and my work around was to create an HTML table with the data.  In my case the workaround was sufficient.  Here is the bug:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79159343

Comment: Thank you! I am looking for a work around that will work for my application. I will look into making an HTML table.